# CF7 Populate Text Field Based On Checkbox Checked

Tags: jquery, plugin-contact-form-7

I need to be be able to auto populate a text field with "one-hidden" when a customer checks a checkbox but so far examples I've found online do not seem to work or im putting them in the wrong place.

```
$('#flight-include').change(function(){
    $("#one-control").text("");
    if ($('#flight-include').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#one-control").text("one-hidden"); 
    }
});
```

I put the above in the function file and it did nothing so guessing im doing something wrong or missing something.

flight-control is the checkbox, one-control is the text field. "one-hidden" is the text that needs to appear in the text field when the flight-include box is checked.

Can someone help as im pretty clueless with this type of coding. Many thanks

Tried executing the code above in the function file but possible not the right place.

Answer (score 1):

assuming it is input text field, changing a text field should use

`$("#one-control").val("one-hidden");`

Comment: Thanks. I made the change but now get the following error in function.php 

syntax error, unexpected token "[", expecting variable or "{" or "$"

Comment: Using your code in the question, just replace .text with .val

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing all of the code, in particular how you are trying to get this to work in your `functions.php` file. There are a few ways to include custom Javascript code, but in using `functions.php`, make sure you are doing something like the following, in this case hooking into the `wp_head` action hook:

```
function cf7_custom_javascript() {
?>
<script>
// your javascript code goes here
</script>
<?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'cf7_custom_javascript');
```

**UPDATE**: It turns out with CF7 you can't target a checkbox by its ID or class, since according to the documentation it applies the ID and/or class to the element wrapper (span tag). You can target the element directly, but that may only work if it's the only checkbox on the form or you may be able to target by some other attribute, like `name`.

The sample code below works, but only if there is just one checkbox on the form:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('#one-control').val("one-hidden");
        } else {
            $('#one-control').val("");
        }
    });
});
```

(note the wrapper used since I've run into issues with using jQuery in my set up)

You should still use the example I provided above in your `functions.php` file or in a custom plugin.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that changes nothing in CF7.